# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to write a program for my biology class in school. It should 'translate' a tripple combination of the four letters A, C, U and G [an X stands for the possibility that A, C, U and G can stand there]. An example is GCX.. GCX is the tripplet for Alanine.

The program should get the Input (the tripplets) and print the amino acid of this tripplet in a label in my GUI (tkinter).

For making it easier I just include the example with GCX and Alanine- it should print "Alanine [Ala]" in the Lable even if I typed 'gcx' in the entry.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

# Interface Construction

# Basic Interface
root = Tk()
root.title("Genetic Translator")
root.geometry("300x175")

# Solid Label "Information for Input"
s_label2 = Label(root, text = "\nInput Tripplet which decodes for an amino acid:\n")
s_label2.pack()

# Mainentry line (tripplet = trip)
trip = Entry(root)
trip.pack()

# .upper() Function
trip = str(trip)
trip = trip.upper()

# Output Function (Trans:    trip -in- AS)
def Input():
    output = tk.StringVar(output)
    o_screen.configure(text = (output.get()))

if trip == "GCX":
    output = "Alanine [Ala]"
    Input()
else:
    output = "Unknown tripplet!"

# Space Label 1
space_label1 = Label(root)
space_label1.pack()

# Button "Confirm"
mainbutton = Button(root, text = "Confirm", command = Input)
mainbutton.pack()

# Space Label 2
space_label2 = Label(root)
space_label2.pack()

# Output Screen
o_screen = Label(root)
o_screen.pack()

# Mainloop function for Interface Options
mainloop()
```

Comment: `output = tk.StringVar(output)` won't put a global `output` into a stringvar. In a function, a name is either all local, or all global, not both.

Answer (score 1):

Your code errors as you are creating a local variable output inside the function and trying to access it before it is created. Changing the names in your function would fix the error:

```
def Input():
    out = tk.StringVar(output)
    o_screen.configure(text = (out.get()))
```

That would mean the global `output` you create in your if/else block would be used but your code still won't do what you want.

It is much easier to get the text from the Entry using a dict to map input to output:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Genetic Translator")
root.geometry("300x175")

# Solid Label "Information for Input"
s_label2 = Label(root, text = "\nInput Tripplet which decodes for an amino acid:\n")
s_label2.pack()

trip = Entry(root)
trip.pack()


output = {"GCX":"Alanine [Ala]"}
# Output Function (Trans:    trip -in- AS)
def Input():
    o_screen.configure(text=(output.get(trip.get(),"Unknown tripplet!")))

# Space Label 1
space_label1 = Label(root)
space_label1.pack()

# Button "Confirm"
mainbutton = Button(root, text = "Confirm", command = Input)
mainbutton.pack()

# Space Label 2
space_label2 = Label(root)
space_label2.pack()

# Output Screen
o_screen = Label(root)
o_screen.pack()

# Mainloop function for Interface Options
root.mainloop()
```

Using  `"Unknown tripplet!"` as the default arg to `dict.get` will mean if the user enters anything you don't have as a key in your dict will mean that will be displayed.

Comment: Oh yeah - it's working perfectly: Thanks to you, it helped me so much.. Thanks :)

Comment: And how can I include more entrys in this dictionary? So that "AUG" gives the Output "Methionine [Met]" for example? And how can I set a ".upper()"-command on my entries?

Comment: @J.Doe, you can add more pairings `k:v`